# store retrieved value in a variable php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

```
$check="SELECT timestamp 
        FROM med_buy
        WHERE patient_id='$pid' AND med_id='$mid'
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

i am using this code i want to store the topmost value returned from the data base
And i want to chcek the timestamp with the current day please help me.

Comment: why you people gave me a - marks when someone could really help this... as i am a newbie i am getting doubts and this site is for getting help only right. any way thanks. i got the answer for the above here itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Limit 1 to only get the top row then use

```
$data = mysql_query($check);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$timestamp = $data['timestamp'];
```

Then to check with the current day, use

```
if(date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($timestamp))
{
   echo "today!";
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .... wat to do ?

Comment: the above warning is coming when i execute what u said..

Comment: it worked :) thank u so much i have another doubt.

Comment: actually i want to check , the date in the timestamp is not older than 10 days from today . how can i do that? pleas help me